# Eager Loading is not working laravel 5.3

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5.3, one-to-many, eager-loading

I have three related models.
1.User model

```
public function users_wishlst(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Users_wishlst');
    }
```

2.Product Model

```
public function users_wishlst(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Users_wishlst');
    }
```

3.Users_wishlst model

```
public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }

    public function product(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Product');
    }
```

in users_wishlsts table i have the followibg columns

1. id
2. user_id
3. product_id

I want to get the product info of an users wishlist. I have tried this

```
public function showWishList(){
        $id= Auth::id();
        $WishList = wishlist::with('product')->where(['user_id'=>$id])->get();
        return json_encode($WishList);
    }
```

But this gives me the following error

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column
>   'products.users_wishlst_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from
>   `products` where `products`.`users_wishlst_id` in (1, 2, 3))
>   what is the problem

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing all about your database structure this seems like a problem with your foreign keys. Eloquent tries to automatically guess the key. Based on the error it seems like your products table doesn't contain a users_wishlst_id column (maybe you named it different?). Try looking at you Database and give Laravel the correct foreign_key.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many

Comment: Yes your guess is right. Product table does not contain users_wishlst_id column. My relations might be not correct. I want to create a wishlist for the users. For that i have created a table called users_wishlists where the user id and product id will be saved. Can you help me with the relations or how to do that using eloquent

Comment: In that case this is more like a many-to-many relationship in which your users_wishlists table would be a pivot table between users and products. https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many .